# USB sticks stop working with Windows 10 after being used with a Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: usb, windows, peripherals

I have a problem with my Raspberry Pi 4 2GB that involves USB sticks: I only have a minimal knowledge of both Linux and Raspbian so I don't know how to handle it.

My problem is: each time I use an USB stick to copy files from/to my Raspberry, then that stick stops working with Windows 10.
I mean, when I put it into the Windows 10 computer's USB port again, the light on the stick flashes a few times then it turns off.
And the stick doesn't appear as a drive on the drives list either.

I've tried with the common tricks like removing and inserting it again, or using a different port, or turning off the computer and booting it again, inserting the stick as soon as Windows finishes loading.
Nothing changed.
Even formatting them (FAT32 with Windows Xp) doesn't help, as these sticks keep being unrecognized by Windows 10.

This has happened with three sticks already (with a fourth one decidedly dead after its first Raspberry experience), the latest being a brand-new stick I used with Raspberry first: it worked fine once or twice, then it stopped working like the others.

By the way, when removing them from either computer (Raspberry and Windows) I unmount the sticks as the good-practice procedure requires.

Weirdly, all these sticks work smoothly with Windows Xp.

I can only guess there's something faulty with my Raspberry but I don't know what: any idea what the issue is and, more importantly, how can I solve it?

Comment: when you connect the stick with win10, does it appear in the device-manager and or the volume-manager? When you format em with XP, can you interchange file between XP and the Raspi?

Comment: @schnedan The stick doesn't appear anywhere in Windows 10: the small LED on it flashes a few times (as it regularly does when you connect a stick to a computer and the computer starts reading it), then it shuts off. And there's no sign of the stick being connected anywhere in Windows 10. As for interchanging files between the Raspberry  and Xp, yes it works fine: all of them. The problem is only with Windows 10.

Comment: sounds strange... have you checked the eventlogs in Win10? At least I would expect an Error to be logged.

Comment: You can try to use https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html , which shows every usbdevice connected ever to your Win10. Also you can purge that information, so Windows10 then can redetect the device like it is the first time. Sometimes that helps...

Comment: what do you do to prepare the USB stick for use with the RPi?

Comment: Taking advantage of your hints, today I’ve been able to experiment a bit and finally found out the problem isn’t caused by the Raspberry as I thought but Windows: looks like the USB driver got corrupted somehow. I’ll have to replace or update it. Sorry for asking help for something that isn’t strictly Raspberry-related (but I didn’t know it when I did). I thank you all for you advice.

Comment: Please delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

The Raspberry Pi uses the ext4 [filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system).

Windows uses the NTFS filesystem.

They are incompatible.

Format your USB stick with something like the FAT32 filesystem which should be understood by both.

Comment: I do. But after being connected to the Raspberry, the sticks still keep on being unreadable by Windows. And even formatting them again doesn't help anymore.

Comment: You are doing more than you have reported,

Comment: Are you ejecting the stick from the pi properly?

Comment: @joan OP says in the question the USB sticks are usable in Windows XP but not in Windows 10. Clearly they are not formatted `ext4`. OP says formatting the USB drives FAT32 in Windows XP does not make them readable again in Windows 10.

Comment: @user68186 The OP has not given the full picture of what he is actually doing.  It's pointless speculating and it seems likely the question has nothing actually to do with the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have the same problem, sometimes Win10 would show a bluescreen error messge and reboot. I found if I do a low level format using hddguru.com free format tool then guiformat to format to fat 32 the flash drives stayed stable on windows. Not sure why but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is rather strange. I often use Win 10 and USb sticks so far absolutely no problem. I keep wondering if the USB Ports on your Rpi are perhaps defect. Have you tried another RPi?

Perhaps trying this SD/SSD Formatter may help  SD Card Formatter ::
https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter/